# Implementing multitasking for Samsung Tizen TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

we are developing an samsung tizen os app.
i found out that multitaking feature is a mandatory to publish the app.
there were docs regarding the implementation of multitaking
but i could not find it helpful there
So if there is a way to implement multitaking then how should i do it
can anybody here explain me in simple language here so that we can submit our app for QA.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Regarding Multitasking for Samsung Tizen TV: visit this page and select "Multitasking" in the right pane. https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/development-checklist/common.html     I think.. Multitasking means Application must be able to do interaction without blocking.

Comment: but this document was not helpful at all as this is very complicated to implement so can you please help me in implementing this in easier way

Comment: Please explain the use case so we can help. Multitasking can be done in a variety of ways based on the use case.

Comment: suppose i'm playing a vod or series and then i use home button to navigate to another app like you tube an dthen come back to our player so the player should resuyme playing the content where i left

Comment: my app is with different html pages and the player page is vodplayer.html

Comment: please if you can help it would be very nice. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to make changes in your config.xml file and in your JS code.

Here can find Samsung Sample, that demonstrates how you can implement multitasking when using the AVPlay API. - https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerAVPlayMultitasking

1. Changes in config.xml. Add line

   <tizen:metadata key="http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/multitasking.support" value="true"/>
2. Listeners in your app

   ```
        /**
         * Enable multitasking
         */
        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange",function(){
            //When going away from this app suspend player
            if( document.hidden ){ // PAUSE
                player.suspend();
            } else { // RESUME
                //When going back to this app resume player
                player.resume();
            }
        }); 

   .....

    /**
     * Suspend playback for multitasking
     */
    suspend: function () {
        webapis.avplay.pause();
        webapis.avplay.suspend();
    },

    /**
     * resume playback for multitasking
     */
    resume: function () {
        webapis.avplay.restore();
        webapis.avplay.play();
    },
   ```